# RuntimeError during Gradient Computation with Custom YOLOv7 Model Wrapper in PyTorch for Xplique Object Detection Explainability

Tags: python, pytorch, in-place, yolov7

I'm working on object detection explainability using the [Xplique](https://github.com/deel-ai/xplique) library with a custom YOLOv7 model analogous to a tutorial designed for ssdlite320_mobilenet_v3_large [Google Colab Tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1X3Yq7BduMKqTA0XEheoVIpOo3IvOrzWL#scrollTo=qjSOyLOgRuhq).

My goal is to use Xplique's Saliency method to generate explanations for detections made by YOLOv7. However, I'm encountering a RuntimeError related to gradient computation during the explanation phase.

**Approach:**

To ensure the YOLOv7 model's output tensors retain the grad_fn attribute, I've wrapped the model in a custom PyTorch module, ensuring compatibility with Xplique's requirements:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Ensemble(nn.ModuleList):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ensemble, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x, augment=False):
        y = []
        for module in self:
            y.append(module(x, augment=augment)[0])  # Ensure augment is passed correctly
        y = torch.cat(y, 1)  # nms ensemble
        return y, None  # inference, train output

# Load the YOLOv7 model and ensure it's ready for inference
model = Ensemble().to(device)  # Assuming device is defined
ckpt = torch.load(weights_path, map_location=device)  # Assuming weights_path is defined
model.append(ckpt['ema' if ckpt.get('ema') else 'model'].float().fuse().eval())

# Compatibility updates
for m in model.modules():
    if type(m) in [nn.Hardswish, nn.LeakyReLU, nn.ReLU, nn.ReLU6, nn.SiLU]:
        m.inplace = True  # PyTorch 1.7.0 compatibility
    elif type(m) is nn.Upsample:
        m.recompute_scale_factor = None  # PyTorch 1.11.0 compatibility

# Ensure your input tensor is on the same device as the model
visualizable_torch_inputs = visualizable_torch_inputs.to(device)

# Now perform inference
predictions = model(visualizable_torch_inputs)
```

With the model prepared, I performed inference to obtain predictions, which include the bounding boxes, confidence scores, and class IDs.

**Issue:**

When attempting to compute explanations using Xplique's Saliency method, the following RuntimeError is raised:

```
RuntimeError: RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [1, 3, 20, 20, 6]], which is output 0 of SigmoidBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 0 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

This occurs precisely at the line:

```
explanation = explainer.explain(processed_tf_inputs, man_bounding_box)
```

Questions:

- How can I resolve the RuntimeError related to gradient computation when using Xplique with a YOLOv7 model?
- Are there specific considerations or modifications required to make YOLOv7 compatible with Xplique's explainability methods?
- Is the issue related to how YOLOv7's outputs are structured or how gradients are being computed within the model or Xplique?